# Mapping data from two Firestore collections with js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections namely:`CURRENCY-PAIR` and `Alerts`.

The `CURRENCY-PAIR` collection contains the following;

- Currency-Pair Name
- Currency-AskPrice
- Currency-BidPrice

The `Alerts` collection contains the following:

- Alert_id
- Alert_Status

How can i map the  `Currency-Pair Name` from the `CURRENCY-PAIR`  collection and `Alert_Status` from the `Alerts` collection to a list showing both.

Comment: What have you already tried? And can you give an example of how you actually want the final output to look like? What do you mean by list showing both? An array? A JS object? A HTML list?

Comment: I haven't tried yet. I'm stuck.I want it to return a js object

Comment: How do you want the outcome to look like? Are you asking about how to fetch data from two firestore collections?

Comment: Yes. How to fetch data from two firestore collections and map them as objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you want to fetch a collection of data from firestore, you should first get the reference of the collection:

```
const currencyRef = firestore().collection('CURRENCY-PAIR');
const alertRef = firestore().collection('Alert_Status');
```

You could then use these references to get the data from firestore:

```
currencyRef.get()
  .then((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data());
  });
```

As you can see, the data is in the form of a promise, which you have to resolve. The doc.data() is an array of all the data in your collection, in the form of JS objects. 

Since the data comes as a promise, you can create an async fetch function, which resolves the promise, and puts the data in a new array which gets returned.
Maybe you can do something like this:

```
const fetchAllCurrencies = async () => {
  const obj = []; // empty array to put collections in
  const currencyRef = firestore().collection('CURRENCY-PAIR'); // ref
  const snapshot = await currencyRef.get() // resolve promise from firestore
  snapshot.forEach((doc) => { // loop over data
    obj.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }); // push each collection to array
  });
  return obj; // return array with collection objects 
}
```

You may create a similar function for the alert collection. 
I'm not entirely sure about what you mean with: 'How can i map the Currency-Pair Name from the CURRENCY-PAIR collection and Alert_Status from the Alerts collection to a list showing both.' 
by creating functions like the one above, you can get arrays of collection js objects. You can combine two arrays with:

```
const newArray = array1.concat(array2);
```

This will melt two arrays into one. It's probably not what you want to do. If I were you, I'd keep the two arrays separate.