# How to fetch data from two firestore collection, merge and display it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections namely `CURRENCY_PAIR` and `CURRENCY_PAIR_LIMIT`. The `CURRENCY_PAIR` collection has the following fields in each document:

- CurrencyPair_Name
- CurrencyPair_id
- Currency_AskPrice
- Currency_BidPrice

and the`CURRENCY_PAIR_LIMIT` collection contain the following fields in each document:

- Limit_id
- Limit_Buy_Price_Threshhold
- Limit_Sell_Price_Threshhold
- Limit_Currency_Pair_Id (references to the Currencypair_Id in the `CURRENCY_PAIR` collection)

I wanted to map each CurrencyPair_Name to its respective Limit_Buy_Price_Threshhold and Limit_Sell_Price_Threshhold then display them in react but i'm stuck. How can i get around this.

Comment: Hi, didn't you ask a similar question yesterday? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64943348/mapping-data-from-two-firestore-collections-with-js

Comment: Yes..This is clearer